# CKEditor 4 - Can't add Widget

Tags: ckeditor

I'm making a simple plugin to add a `Richcombo` to the toolbar that will insert a widget when one of the options in the dropdown menu is clicked.

Here's the code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'myPlugin', {

    init : function( editor )
    {
        editor.widgets.add( 'widget1' );
        editor.ui.addRichCombo( 'richcombo1', {...} );  
    }

});
```

Under `chrome > inspect element> console`, 
it says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`
I'm using version `4.4.5`

Please help, nobody replies on CKEditor's forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [widget](http://ckeditor.com/addon/widget) plugin. Otherwise the `editor.widgets` object does not exist, hence error.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'myPlugin', {
    // Load the widget plugin.
    requires: 'widget',

    init : function( editor )
    {
        editor.widgets.add( 'widget1', {
            // Your widget definition...
        } );
    }

} );
```

For more, see the tutorial about [creating simple widget](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1).